# KDE 5 in Debian wheezy?

Tags: debian, kde, desktop-environment, display-manager

I really hate the look of all the desktop environments officially supported by Debian 7. I also really really like the look of KDE Plasma 5. Unfortunately Debian seems to only support KDE 4, and it looks extremely ugly. If there is any way I could compile the desktop environment and display manager myself I would like to know. I do NOT want any of the software that comes with it, only the desktop environment and login screen.

I also don't want to use testing or unstable distros even though I know that KDE 5 is supported there.

Comment: "If there is any way I could compile the desktop environment and display manager myself I would like to know." Download the source code and compile it?

Comment: You could probably backport the KDE environment and display manager from a more recent version of Debian. But it would be quite a lot of work; I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to upgrade to Debian Sid then KDE5 can be installed very easily with the Siduction repos, instructions here:

[My Blog Entry on the Subject](http://tombh.co.uk/plasma5-(kde5)-debian-sid/)

Comment: Better if you copy the relevant parts of your blog entry here, don't make disappointment to the googlers of the future...